# How to make experience editor editable If List of data inside the map

Tags: experience-editor, jss

I am retrieving the date from the service and I am mapping and displaying the details of what service gives in that what are the common text details which need to come from Sitecore it displays it's fine but what is my question is -> whatever I am displaying the details from Sitecore in Experience editor it is not displaying and how to make it as experience editable.

Example:

`const Points = ({ dataSource, rendering, sitecoreContext }) => 
{ return (<div>{weekGroup.ActivityList && weekGroup.ActivityList.map((point, index) => (point.EventDate && isExperienceEditorActive() ? 
( <Text field={dataSource.Today} //Here I am getting the data from sitecore but this static data is not displayin in the experience editor ? please help me on this 
 />)))} 
</div>)}`

In code any braces missing and all please don't consider that this is how i am approching please guide me on this how we can acheive in experience editor?
Whatever the about text it has to be editable in? but currently, I am unable to edit it I have tried many things but no luck. Please find below:

1. `isExperienceEditorActive()` --> not working
2. `props.sitecoreContext` --> not working
3. `sitecoreContext.pageEditing`--> not working

Please help me on this Advance thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add more detail here please. What have you tried and what diagnosis have you done.

Comment: @RichardSeal Thak you for your comment.I am Mapping the data inside loop it 's like this {weekGroup.activity list &&
                    weekGroup.ActivityList.map((point, index) => ({point.EventDate &&
                            isExperienceEditorActive() ? (
                              <Text field={componentData.Today} /> // These details are coming from Sitecore but in experience editor, I am unable to view this data and it should be editable and it's a static data based on the condition I am displaying that 
                            )}

Comment: Please update the post rather than add code into the comments section

Comment: @RichardSeal Suree i am updating that